# touch event when finger moves to next view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I am dragging my finger and it moves to the next view. Both views implement setOnTouchListener().

How to find out that the finger is now on second view.

ACTION_MOVE is getting returned for first view even though my finger is on second view.

Do I need to implement any other listener?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.textview.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello_world1" />

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello_world2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.textview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txt1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            TextView txt1 =  (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
            Log.d("txt1.getText()",txt1.getText().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

     txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    txt1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            TextView txt1 =  (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
            Log.d("txt1.getText()",txt1.getText().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });


     txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
    txt1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            TextView txt1 =  (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
            Log.d("txt1.getText()",txt1.getText().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the current MotionEvent x and y is in the 2nd view hit rect

```
            Rect viewHitRect = new Rect();
        secondView.getHitRect(viewHitRect);
        if(viewHitRect.contains((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY())) {//You are in 2nd view}
```

Comment: My text views are added dynamically. After  doing new I am adding setOnTouchListener

Comment: In that case here you can get the hitrect for the first view by that you will know if finger has moved out of the first view.

Comment: Yes. But I am adding 26 views in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

When finger is coming on `textview2`, it will get **ACTION_HOVER_ENTER** and

`textview1` will get **ACTION_HOVER_EXIT**

Check on these parameters, **ACTION_MOVE** will be given to `textview1` as you mentioned but `hover` parameter clearly decide which `textfield` is under finger at this time

**UPDATE :**

If finger is clicked on `views` then you will get **ACTION_DOWN** on `textview2` and parallely `textview1` will get **ACTION_UP**

Comment: The finger is pressed and not hovering on the screen. Still hover event will be called?

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Please check.. if finger is clicked then you will get ACTION_HOVER -> ACTION_DOWN event one by one

Comment: Yes. But in my case the finger is pressed on view1. Now without moving my finger up I dragged and the finger is on second view. How to handle this.

Comment: When your finger goes out of view1 you will get ACTION_UP for view1... when you enter in view2, you will get ACTION_HOVER_ENTER for view2.. check it by putting Logs in these events inside listener

Comment: The other views are not getting any touch event. Only the view on which the finger was pressed is getting the event. When the finger dragged to the other views they did not get any on touch event. Will they get some other event?